# Is there a technical (or slang) term for triggering a game loss due to attempting to draw from an empty library?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does a game-loss triggered by meeting the conditions presented by [CR 121.4](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr121/) have a particular name, or rather is there a technical (or slang) word that indicates a loss via this condition?

Comment: I've heard the term 'milled out' when the deck was actively thrown into the graveyard during the game, but I have no sources with this and it may have been regional.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Yes, the slang term is "to deck" or "to deck out"**

[Decking](https://www.google.com/search?q=mtg+decking), [decking out](https://www.google.com/search?q=mtg+decking+out&oq=mtg+decking+out)

You can use the term transitively or intransitively, i.e. you can say "I decked (out)" meaning you lost due to drawing from an empty library, or "I decked (out) my opponent", meaning you won by milling your opponent to death.

Personally, I've only ever heard "to deck", but apparently both are used.

Comment: In my experience "decked out" is less common than "decked" when there is an object attached (ie "I decked my opponent" is more common than "I decked out my opponent")

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Interesting that outside of the context of MTG, both of those terms have very different meanings.  "Decked out" generally means "lavishly decorated", while "decked" means "knocked to the ground".  (Both work either transitively or intransitively in this case.)

Comment: Never once heard "decked out". Played for over a decade. More common usage would be "I almost got decked/I almost decked them".

Comment: @Our_Benefactors I've found that which gets used depends a lot on the exact group. Some I've played with prefer 'decked out', others prefer just 'decked', but most seem to understand both. I suspect some influence here from other games as well, as there are at least a few where one or the other is the term for that type of loss per the actual rules.

Comment: I've only ever heard "decked out" for the other player, although sometimes I've heard just "decked" for doing it to yourself.  That is, "I decked him out", but never "I decked him" (except once when they meant they literally punched their opponent, anyway); but "I decked myself" and "I decked myself out" were about equal.  SouthEast US here.

Comment: We mostly use the (in most cases incorrect) term: I milled myself. I got milled. I milled you.

Answer (score 16):

Informally known as "decking yourself" (or your opponent). For example, see ChannelFireball's [Temur Reclamation deck guide](https://strategy.channelfireball.com/all-strategy/channelmagic/channelmagic-articles/reclaiming-standard-with-temur-rec/):

> Be careful to not [deck yourself](https://clips.twitch.tv/AmusedFunnyFriesPMSTwin).

(Yes, that is Hall of Famer [LSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Scott-Vargas) decking himself after not checking his deck)

Comment: Decking yourself applies only when your own draws cause your deck to empty - if an opponent mills you (or causes mass draw) it's just decking out.

Comment: Check yourself before you deck yourself.

Comment: I don't think "decking yourself" applies when an opponent causes you to get into this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The actual event of losing the game is getting decked. You may also hear the term "mill". That term originated with the card [Millstone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMillstone%5d), which moved cards from a player's library to their graveyard, and until recently it was an informal term for removing cards from a library, and could be ambiguous as to whether it referred to moving the cards to the graveyard, drawing them, exiling them, etc. However, in M21 (released in 2020), "mill" was made a keyword specifically referring to moving cards from a player's library to their graveyard. Thus, while forcing a player to draw cards does remove cards from their library, it is not milling. Milling does not directly cause a game loss; only when the player is required to draw from their empty library do they lose. However, decking and milling are still closely connected, since milling sets a player up to deck themselves.

Comment: "However, in 2021" My calender is still in 2020. When did this happen?

Comment: @Mast in the core set M21, pronounced "Magic 2021", which released in 2020

Comment: @Caleth Ah, set 2021. It looked like it referred to a date.